# Insert current date inside HTML text for emails

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I want to send outlook email from excel.

I need to insert today's date inside the HTML code.

**"strDate"** in the email body does not work when trying to format the date.

I tried replace function, Format (Date) and other ways.

```vb
Sub SharePerformance1()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xOutMsg As String
    Dim strDate As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    strDate = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy")
    xOutMsg = "Good morning!<br />This pay period is from <b><span style=""color:#CE0426"">&strDate&</span style=""color:#CE0426""></b>To help ensure you are paid accurately and timely, please follow the instructions below.<br /><br />" & _
              "<u>Salaried team members</u><br />" & _
              "<span style=font-size:5px>&#9679;</span> Reason e.g. sick, vacation, jury duty<br /><br />" & _
              "Thank you!"
                  
    With xOutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Notice" & Format(Now() + 1, "dddd, mmmm dd") & " for Pay Period " & Format(Now() - 8, "dd") & "-" & Format(Now() + 3, "dd/yyyy")
        .HTMLBody = xOutMsg
        .Display
    End With
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What does *does not work* mean? Does everything else work?

Comment: "strDate" should be displayed as the current date, for example "03/25/2021". But when I tried to run the code, it displayed the word "strDate" instead. If I don't use HTML to color or run it only, it could show "03/25/2021".

Comment: You've got `strDate` inside quotes instead of outside quotes. Probably one of the posted solutions will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine here: (*Note: Edited per @NickAbbot to remove extra ampersands*)

```vb
xOutMsg = "Good morning!<br />This pay period is from <b><span style=""color:#CE0426"">" & strDate & ". </span style=""color:#CE0426""></b>To help ensure you are paid accurately and timely, please follow the instructions below.<br /><br />" & _
              "<u>Salaried team members</u><br />" & _
              "<span style=font-size:5px>&#9679;</span> Reason e.g. sick, vacation, jury duty<br /><br />" & _
              "Thank you!"
```

Also, what kind of error are you expecting in routine use?  Usually not a good idea to have an unqualified `On Error Resume Next` unless you know you will only get a single error which can be ignored.

Here is a screenshot of the rendered text:

[image]

Comment: @NickAbbot Thanks. It's been a long time since I've written in HTML.  I removed them and add a full stop after the date.

Comment: I really really appreciate your answer! It works now. Cannot believe it ! I spent several days but it just takes you guys a few minutes to find out solution!

Answer (score 2):

The variable `strDate` needs to be outside the quotes. I've fixed that in the code below and also tidied things up a bit. In particular I've broken the creation of the HTML into multiple lines which should hopefully make it easier to maintain, debug and add to.

```
Sub SharePerformance1()
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xOutMsg As String
Dim strDate As String

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    strDate = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy")
    xOutMsg = xOutMsg & "Good morning!<br><br>"
    xOutMsg = xOutMsg & "This pay period is from <b><span style=""color:#CE0426"">" & strDate & "</span></b><br><br>"
    xOutMsg = xOutMsg & "To help ensure you are paid accurately and timely, please follow the instructions below.<br><br>"
    xOutMsg = xOutMsg & "<u>Salaried team members</u><br>"
    xOutMsg = xOutMsg & "<ul><li>Reason e.g. sick, vacation, jury duty</li></ul><br>"
    xOutMsg = xOutMsg & "Thank you!"
                  
    With xOutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Notice " & Format(Now() + 1, "dddd, mmmm dd") & " for Pay Period " & Format(Now() - 8, "dd") & "-" & Format(Now() + 3, "dd/yyyy")
        .HTMLBody = xOutMsg
        .Display
    End With
    
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

[image: Message generated by above code.]

Comment: If I put strDate to be ourside the quotes, it displays only the word "strDate", not a date :(

Answer (score 0):

Two Changes:

1. You need a space after "Notice"
   .Subject = "Notice " & Format...
2. Not this &strDate&
   This: " & strDate & "

Comment: I did try this way before and it does not work neither!

Comment: You need both quotes: ...426"">" & strDate & "</spa...